# Cannot assign chars from one string to another

Tags: c, mud

So I have a function that takes a string, and strips out special format characters, and assigns it to another string for later processing.

A sample call would be:

```
act_new("$t does $d");
```

It should strip out the $t and the $d and leave the second string as " does ", but its not assigning anything. I am getting back into programming after quite a few years of inactivity, and this is someone elses code (A MUD codebase, Rom), but I feel like I am missing something fundamental with pointer assignments. Any tips?

(This is truncated code, the rest has no operations on str or point until much later)

```
void act_new(const char *format)
{
  const char *str;
  char *point;

  str = format;

  while ( *str != '\0' ) {
    if ( *str != '$' ) {
      *point++ = *str++;
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to modify in-place or create a new string?

Comment: Your `point` pointer doesn't point to anything. And, even if it did, you don't have a mechanism by which to return it to the caller of your function.

Comment: Greg, what is the value of `point`, the first time `*point++ = *str++;` is executed?

Comment: You don't need `continue` at the end of a loop. Loops automatically continue unless you break out.

Comment: You only increment `str` when it points to `$`. In other cases, you keep testing the same character and get an infinite looop.

Comment: You're only skipping the `$` character, not the character after it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment `str` every time through the loop, not only when you assign to `point`. Otherwise you end up in an infinite loop when the character doesn't match the `if` condition.

You also want to skip the character after `$`, so you have to increment `str` twice when you encounter `$`.

The code is simpler if you use a `for` loop and array indexing rather than pointer arithmetic.

```
size_t len = strlen(format);
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (format[i] == '$') {
        i++; // extra increment to skip character after $
    } else {
        *point++ = format[i];
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code, as pointed out in the comments:

- `point` is not initialized (garbage pointer value)
- `continue` doesn't do anything
- infinite loop if a `$` is encountered

When writing the function, one must also keep in mind to skip an extra character if a `$` is encountered if and only if it's not the last character in the string (except for the `'\0'`).

Since you know how many times you need to loop, a `for` loop is better suited and, as a bonus, you don't have to explicitly check if the character after a `$` is `'\0'` when skipping an extra character in `format` (renamed `src` below). Also, don't forget to terminate the destination string.

This code will take care of those things for you:

```
void act_new(const char *src)
{
    const size_t length = strlen(src);
    char * const dst = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(length+1));
    if(dst == NULL)
        // Error handling left out
        return;

    char *point = dst;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        if(src[i] == '$')
        {
            ++i;
            continue;
        }
        *point++ = src[i];
    }
    *point = '\0';  //Terminate string properly

    printf("%s\n", dst);
    free(dst);
}
```